# We're no longer sketchy; someone should update the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

As the title says, we're now sketchy-less and the FAQ needs updating.

**Edit:** Posted to Meta.SO [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127692/were-no-longer-sketchy-someone-should-update-the-faq).

Comment: Yeah, that's not part of the FAQ we can edit, so this is definitely a core team request.

Comment: I don't believe it's been yet removed from all beta sites.  I expect they'll remove it after that is complete.

Comment: I just realized that maybe this could have been migrated to Meta.SO? I hadn't even thought that meta questions might migrate before reposting, sorry.